# tftp non-intearctive mode not working

Tags: scripting, kali-linux, tftp

tftp inline not working

```
root@kali:~/scripts/recon_enum/exploit-db# tftp -v 192.xxx.xx.xxx 69 -c get text.txt text.txt
usage: tftp host-name [port]
tftp>
```

but its working in interactive mode:

```
root@kali:~/scripts/recon_enum/exploit-db# tftp 192.XXX.XX.XXX
tftp> status
Connected to 192.xxx.xx.xxx.
Mode: netascii Verbose: off Tracing: off
Rexmt-interval: 5 seconds, Max-timeout: 25 seconds
tftp> get test.txt
Received 16 bytes in 0.0 seconds
tftp> quit
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you check manual page for [`tftp(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/tftp.1.html)? Ubuntu version does not support any of your options you provided, so it is no wonder it does not work.

You can probably try something like

```
tftp 192.XXX.XX.XXX <<< "get text.txt text.txt"
```

or you can build some [other version](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tftp) which provides these options.